# Issue in adding resource to registry path in wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 APIM 2.5.0 and WSo2 IS 5.6.0 and they are well integrated and token management is working fine without issue.

I am now trying to add API using REST API to APIM server and I am getting below error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-04-26 10:56:29,403] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: a2bfc1b1-f5ec-4316-b7d6-9e7d54e0213b. Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:205)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:949)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:221)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.addGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2600)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:672)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:577)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addResourceWithoutContentId(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1404)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.add(JDBCResourceDAO.java:448)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.addEmptyCollection(Repository.java:1198)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.addEmptyCollection(Repository.java:1156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.add(Repository.java:1013)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:717)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:292)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addResourceWithoutContentId(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1385)
    ... 83 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-04-26 10:56:29,413] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider} -  Error while performing registry transaction operation {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider}
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: a2bfc1b1-f5ec-4316-b7d6-9e7d54e0213b. Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.addGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2600)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:672)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:577)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:205)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:949)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:221)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addResourceWithoutContentId(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1404)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.add(JDBCResourceDAO.java:448)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.addEmptyCollection(Repository.java:1198)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.addEmptyCollection(Repository.java:1156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.add(Repository.java:1013)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:717)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:292)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addResourceWithoutContentId(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1385)
    ... 83 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-04-26 10:56:29,415] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} -  Error while adding new API : user@user.com-verificationAPI-1.0.0 - Error while performing registry transaction operation {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:1617)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2666)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:672)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:577)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: a2bfc1b1-f5ec-4316-b7d6-9e7d54e0213b. Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.addGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2600)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI. String or binary data would be truncated.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:205)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:801)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:221)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add resource to path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/user@user.com/verificationAPI
```

Seems like when I am trying to add API in APIM (using correct token), I am getting error which says that it cannot add user@user.com in registry path(/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/...).

Can some one please help me

Thanks

Comment: one of the columns in REG_RESOURCE is too small in mssql.

Comment: @dagget do we have increase the length of the column in REG_RESOURCE?

Comment: i believe yes. i had such problem. but don't remember the column name

Comment: these are the columns (REG_NAME, REG_CREATOR, REG_MEDIA_TYPE, REG_LAST_UPDATOR, REG_DESCRIPTION and REG_UUID) which has type as varchar. REG_CREATOR and REG_LAST_UPDATOR has only limit of 31. So, these are the ones which I should consider to increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the varchar limit of `REG_CREATOR` & `REG_LAST_UPDATOR` from `REG_RESOURCE` table.

After doing this, stop the `WSO2` delete the `/solr` directory from `<APIM_HOME>` (it's your wso2 directory as `/var/opt/WSO2AM-2.5.0`) & start the `WSO2`.

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks @Ashwink.
If we consider these as 2 steps, in my case 1st one already fulfilled and I had to perform the second step. After that the fresh deployment started as expected.